# parsing text for contents of database table of limited size

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I have a MySQL table of "people" as part of a web site, for example:

```
| people_id  | firstname  | lastname    |
-----------------------------------------
| 1          | John       | Lennon      |
| 2          | Paul       | McCartney   |
| 3          | George     | Harrison    |
| 4          | Ringo      | Starr       |
| .          | .          | .           |
```

My table has about 2000 rows.

I also have a "news" section on the web site. Frequently, these news items contain references to "people", e.g.

> John Lennon and Paul McCartney wrote
>   some of the most popular songs in the
>   history of rock music.

Is it possible (or reasonable/advisable) to automatically parse each item of news to look for "people" who are in the database, and then turn them into links. So, for example, the above text would be turned into this (or something functionally equivalent):

```
<a href="/people/1>John Lennon</a> and <a href="/people/2">Paul McCartney</a> wrote some of the most popular songs in the history of rock music.
```

What would be the best way to do this? I've made a few abortive attempts to do it using regular expressions in php, but I guess this is not the best approach. I don't known much about javascript (and its frameworks) but I would be happy to use this if it makes sense to do so.

This is not an essential feature of the web site (but I feel it would be a nice addition) so I would prefer to omit such a feature rather than increasing the page load time dramatically.

**EDIT**

I left out some details in the initial question, to keep the length down.

In fact it is the web site for a football club - all of the "people" are members of the web site, and can log in, and add and edit news stories (for example, match reports), in which they frequently refer to other "people". So it's not just me who adds the news stories - they can be added by the (around) 2000 other users.

Although the membership is restricted in that people have to be approved before joining, the system has to be able to cope with complexities such as people with unusual names, and there are a few instances of more than one people with the same name.

I have implemented a kind of solution, in which I use a type of proprietary code to mark up/down people's names (e.g. [p=1]John Lennon[/p]) but I have found that, of the 2000 users of the site, only a handful make use of this.

For what it's worth, the web site is www.ouafc.com, and an example of a news story is at www.ouafc.com/news/312.

Comment: This can be tricky - how would you handle "the John Lennon Foundation", for example? Linking just the name would probably still look like you intended to link to the Foundation...

Comment: @OrbMan, Even in that scenario (although I understand the point entirely, don't get me wrong) as long as it references the same *John Lennon* it would still be correct. Depending on implementation, if the link were made from the beginning of *John* and then *Lennon* as long as the *Foundation* part wasn't linked along with it.

Comment: Technically correct, but usability suffers. Another edge case is substring matching where you have both `John Smith` and `John Smith Jones` users - you have to watch for double-embedded linking situations.

Comment: Sounds like an interesting idea to me. Since you presumably control the database, I'm sure you could find ways to deal with potential name clashes like the John Smith example. I assume the site's content is fairly specific, so people should know that if there's a link to a guy running for president with the name John Lennon, it's probably not the guy from... what was it... the Monkeys?  ;o)

Comment: @OrbMan - yes that is a very good point, and one which I think put paid to my attempts to solve it using regular expressions.

Comment: @patrick - yes I control the database, but would like it to be as "open" as possible

Comment: I set up this web site over 2 years ago, and I have not implemented this feature because of all the problems, which have been alluded to. I didn't want my question to be too long, so I left out some details - I will add more details to the question.

Comment: A possible workaround for some issues may be to use a reg exp to check for capitalization of adjacent words so that 'John Smith' would not receive a link if 'Jones' comes after it, and 'John Lennon' will not if 'The' comes before or 'Foundation' comes after. There won't be any perfect solution as names are not necessarily unique, but I'm sure you could find workarounds to make it function properly most of the time.

Comment: @patrick - yes this is a good idea, which I have explored in a limited form. I came up against some difficult names, such as "Rossa O'Keefe-O'Donovan" which i could never quite manage to integrate into the system. But maybe I should explore this further.

Comment: @Tomba - Yeah, there will be some tricky ones. I personally hate staring at reg exps but they can be handy. Probably better to make things more strict so that fewer links are created but with a higher degree of accuracy. Best of luck to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know much about php, but here's a quick JavaScript go at it using jQuery 1.4:

```
<div id="maindiv">
   John Lennon and Paul McCartney wrote some of the most popular songs in the history of rock music.
</div>


<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
       myPage.linkify($("#maindiv"));
    })

var myPage = {
    map: {
            "John Lennon": 1,
            "Paul McCartney": 2,
            "Rock Music": 3
         },

    linkify: function(domEl){
        var htmlcopy = domEl.html();

        function buildLink(txt, loc){
            return '<a "href = /blah/'+loc+'>'+txt+'</a>';
        }

        for(i in myPage.map){
           var tmpStr = new RegExp(i,"gi");
           htmlcopy = htmlcopy.replace( tmpStr, buildLink(i, myPage.map[i]) );
       }

       domEl.html(htmlcopy);
    }
 }
</script>
```

myPage.map would be built server-side from the database. This could also be a callback to an Ajax function (that would grab the map) so that it wouldn't stop the rest of the page from doing its thing.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to type that out. I have not used any javascript on the site, but this looks like a perfect use for it. It'll take me a while to get to grips with jquery but I've been meaning to do that for some time now. I don't think I would want myPage.map to be visible to users of the site so I'd have to look into doing it via Ajax.

Comment: If you don't want your users to be able to see the map, then a client-side approach is not going to be a good option. Anything that goes across the wire is available to the viewer, including Ajax responses. There are some server-side JS implementations, but you're probably better off recreating this in php in that case.

Comment: maybe I'll have to rethink whether I need myPage.map to be invisible

Comment: It works great - thanks. I'm very new to jquery and not experienced in javascript: how would I go about obtaining myPage.map through an Ajax function?

Comment: Check out the documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

You'll do something like:
$.getJSON('someurl/getMap.php', function(data) {
  myPage.map = data;
});
Where 'someurl/getMap.php' is a function on the server that builds the JSON version the data you need.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to manually mark up the news posts in some way, to indicate when a name appears.  It's the only way to prevent missed names, or improperly parsed names, and to avoid the huge processing requirement of scanning every news story for every possible name from the database.

Maybe something with a twittery-syntax like:

```
@[John Lennon] and @[Paul McCartney] wrote some of the most popular songs in the history of rock music.
```

Then run it through a custom sort of [markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/)-style function when you want to display the news story.  It could parse those markers out, find the matching DB record, and generate the link.

It'd be more efficient to convert @[] markers to links before inserting the news story in the database, but that couples things more tightly - if a user is deleted or his ID changes, you have a broken link.  Storing the @[] also makes editing stories easier.

#### Update

If you must have the names automagically detected and converted to links, this can be achieved at a pretty severe performance penalty that only grows as you add more names:

```
function linkify_names($news) {
  $people = query('select people_id, firstname, lastname from people');

  $from = $to = array();
  foreach ($people as $person) {
    $name = "$person->firstname $person->lastname";
    // TODO - escape regex chars in $name?

    // match [boundary]$name[boundary], case insensitive
    $from[] = "/(\b)($name)(\b)/i";

    // include boundaries in replacement; maintain case of found name
    $to[] = '$1<a href="/people/' . $person->people_id .'">$2</a>$3';
  }

  return preg_replace($from, $to, $news);
}
```

The difference is, instead of looking up only the names marked with @[] tags, you must look up *all* names, and exhaustively search for each one.  You cannot rely on simple regular expressions to find names in the body of the news document.

Comment: I have in fact implemented this sort of solution already (perhaps I should have mentioned it in the question, but I wanted to keep it simple). However, I consider this to be a less than ideal solution, simply because the "news" items can be added by any one of a number of users of the web site. While I have provided the functionality to add links in a similar way to that in which you suggested - most users of the site do not bother using the functionality. So I would prefer to have an "automatic" way of doing it.